# How to handle dynamic outputs with LearningModelBinding?

Tags: machine-learning, input, dynamic, binding, onnx

I have an onnx model that takes in a fixed set of inputs and produces a variable length output.  This works fine with DirectML when we use the ORT interface, but I'm trying to use Windows.AI.MachineLearning because it (empiricallly speaking) does not crash as often, connects to the GPU on more machines, and properly loads our models.  However, the way the Shape is described by the tensor output is [-1, -1, 80].  I am generically using this as so:

```
TensorFloat outputTensor = TensorFloat.Create(tfd.Shape);
```

This throws an exception.  I looked at the documentation for the LearningModelBinding and also the TensorFloat and do not see any way to pre-populate the binding with an output that is of an unspecified length.  Little help here?

(for reference, the model in question is FastSpeech2)

Passing in the shape that is stored in the model should always work, and do whatever is right to process the model.  I have tried running this on Windows 10 and Windows 11 both, does not work.